# How to loop through array in watson?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to show the Options on Watson Assistant which are dynamic from an array. How can I loop through the array from the context and display it in the output/response in the form of Options?

```
    {
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "title": "This is a test",
        "options": [

          {
            "label": "<? $my_options_array[0].label ?>",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "<? $my_options_array[0].label ?>"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "<? $my_options_array[1] ?>",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "<? $my_options_array[1] ?>"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "response_type": "option"
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "my_options_array": "<? $availableWorkFlows.split(',') ?>"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no easy way to loop within Watson Assistant. The size of the array will determine how easy it is to create a mechanism to handle the required output. One such method is to use a set of conditional responses within one dialog node. Each response is configured to the size of the array. i.e. condition $my_options_array.length() == 3, so output is $my_options_array[2], $my_options_array[1], $my_options_array[0], next conditional response would be $my_options_array.length() == 2, output  $my_options_array[1], $my_options_array[0], then condition $my_options_array.length() ==  1, etc.

Comment: like @timd said, you could also create options as response type and populate the values from my_options. However this requires to create a pre defined no of options. like if $my_options_array.length() == 3, then create a option with 3 rows and .....